# Browse for a file and store the path in a function

Tags: python, file, tkinter, directory

I created a function that search for a .txt file in a folder, and then it read it and print the results in another .txt file.

```
import os


# this will check for the file list file in the d3 folder

def file_list():
    for f_name in os.listdir('D:\\d3 Projects\\python_test'):

        if f_name.endswith('.txt'):
            print(f_name)

            # this will read and print the filelist.txt file

            myfile = open("D:\\d3 Projects\\python_test\\filelist.txt", "r")
            contents = myfile.read()
            myfile.close()
            print(contents)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list()
```

Now I would like to make the input path and the output path user selectable, with a little interface. (I was thinking using tkinter.)

Any idea on how i can make it?
I was able to create the window and the browse button, but I don't know how to store it in my function.

Comment: Tkinter supports [native file dialogs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
 
 
 
class Root(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Python Tkinter Dialog Widget")
        self.minsize(640, 400)
        self.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')
 
        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)
 
        self.button()
 
 
 
    def button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse A File",command = self.fileDialog)
        self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
 
 
    def fileDialog(self):
 
        self.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir =  "/", title = "Select A File", filetype =
        (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")) )
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.labelFrame, text = "")
        self.label.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.label.configure(text = self.filename)
 
 
 
 
 
root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can try this for a little interface

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did the interface, I just wanted to understand how to store the path I get from the file dialogue into my function. Here: